# Função gets em Linux

Tags: c, linux

Estou tentando usar a função `gets` (linguagem C), mas ela não funciona. Estou usando ela de forma errada? O código está assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    char nome[40];
    int nota_1;
    int nota_2;
    int nota_3;

}aluno;

int main (){
    aluno a[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Matricula\n");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].matricula);
        printf("Nome\n");
        gets(a[i].nome);
        printf("Nota das provas\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a[i].nota_1, &a[i].nota_2, &a[i].nota_3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sempre informe na sua pergunta qual é o problema que está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 6):

O que acontece é que o gets pega o "\n" que o scanf deixa, tanto é que se você inverter a ordem do scanf com o gets vai funcionar.

Nesse caso, use o fgets como o Broly mencionou, isso vai resolver o seu problema.

Você também pode tentar usar o:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
getc(stdin);
```

Outra forma é você pegar o "\n" que o scanf deixa com o getchar() e então usar o gets, dessa forma aqui também funciona:

```
int main (){
    aluno a[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Matricula\n");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].matricula);
        getchar();
        printf("Nome\n");
        gets(a[i].nome);
        printf("Nota das provas\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a[i].nota_1, &a[i].nota_2, &a[i].nota_3);

    }
}
```

Comment: É, invertendo a ordem funciona mesmo. Mas vou seguir o conselho e usar o fgets. Brigada!

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha em outra solução que eu dei

Comment: posso fazer mais uma pergunta?

Comment: Caso a resposta solucione o seu problema não esqueça de marcá-la como resolvida para que outras pessoas vejam a solução :)

Comment: Eu preciso somar as notas dentro do array de estruturas como faço isso?

Comment: Recomendo abrir outra pergunta para não fugirmos do escopo dessa question aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Só de usar gets() já é um erro :-)

Não, não estou sendo o cara chato da turma, realmente essa função não tem lugar na programação atual e já foi oficialmente removida da linguagem C, porque não há como informar para ela o espaço máximo que ela pode preencher (se o compilador ainda aceita o gets, o problema é dele — não use mesmo assim)

Minha sugestão:

Leia todas as linhas com `fgets`. Quando precisar extrair um número de uma dessas linhas, use `sscanf` (repare que tem um **s** a mais no começo do nome da função). Essa função faz o mesmo que o `scanf`, mas lê de uma string já pronta em vez de ler direto do teclado.